# All applications are terminated by iOS 12 when iPhone is charging

Tags: ios12

I am facing an issue where iOS is terminating all the apps which are in background after the phone is connected for charging (this is only happening on iOS 12+). This does not happen always but happens once in a while. I have also verified that it's not just my app but all apps are killed. If anyone has faced similar issue or knows how to fix this then it would be a great help.

Also this has been reported my by group of testers so its not a device specific issue.

Note : My application is a background location application which is running always.

Comment: Running into a similar issue and it looks like this could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005174/ios-12-terminates-apps-in-the-background-for-no-reason However as of 08.01.2019 there does not seem to be a solution.

Comment: Yes this behaviour is only starting iOS 12 but crashes will happen only after phone is being charged. @chiwi is it same for you as well?

Comment: @PuneetSharma: did you find the cause or even a solution?

Comment: @u01jmg3 I did't found exact reason, but for solution i am using Firebase to wake up my app incrementally (not the best solution but it serves the purpose for my app.) Have you tried iOS 12.3 Beta, may be you can follow this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005174/ios-12-terminates-apps-in-the-background-for-no-reason/53005175?noredirect=1#comment95497031_53005175